# How to sort NSMutableDictionary by values

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have stackes with the problem.

I have NSMutableDictionary, where Values is numbers [1..n], and Keys is words.
I would like to sort this dictionary and words with the biggest numbers in values.

I have tried  when the words are values and numbers are keys, but it is unpossible in my case, because i have same numbers in values.

thanks everyone for help

here is code that i tried to wrote

```
- (void) method
{
    _fourWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray * Keys = [_sentences allKeys];
    NSArray * valuesArray = [_sentences allValues];
    NSArray * sortedValuesArray = [valuesArray      sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSArray * reverseVArray = [[sortedValuesArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

    NSLog(@"%@",reverseVArray);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some actual code so we can what you have and better explain the results that you want.

Comment: OK, you posted some code. What's the problem with it? What do you want it to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: now i sorting only values. but in result i want sort all dictionary named "sentences" by this values.

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary. A dictionary is an unordered collection. You can only sort the arrays you get from allKeys or allValues. That's usually what you want anyway, if you're using that dictionary to populate a table or other kind of ordered list.

Comment: Like @rdelmar said, you can't sort an NSDictionary.  And your description of how you want things sorted is impossible to parse.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you want, but it seems like you want an array of words sorted by the number they're associated with. The following code does this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"name" : @3, @"name2" : @2, @"name3" : @1};
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
  [array addObject:@{@"string" : key, @"number" : obj}];
}];
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
  return [obj1[@"number"] compare:obj2[@"number"]];
}];
```

Then you can use this array as so:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  NSLog(@"String: %@", obj[@"string"]);
}];
```

Or turn it into an array of just the strings

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray new];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  [strings addObject:obj[@"string"]];
}];
```